# I am trying to insert into a table in sql server but its giving an error that Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'of'

Tags: c#

```
                DBConnection objconn = new DBConnection();
              objconn.connection(); //calling connection   

              System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand com = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("tbl_srsdata", objconn.con);
              com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
              var rows = Table1.Items;
     TextBlock field;
              TextBlock type;
              TextBlock datatype;
              TextBlock len;
              TextBlock buis;
              int id;
     id = Redirect.identity;
              MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
              for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
              {
     DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Table1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                  for (int j = 0; j < Table1.Columns.Count; j++)
                  {
                      field = Table1.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                      j++;
                      type = Table1.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                      j++;
                      datatype = Table1.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                      j++;
                      len = Table1.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                      j++;
                      buis = Table1.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                      j++;
    com.CommandText = "insert into tbl_srsdata(id,field,[type_of_control],datatype,length,other_buisness_rules) values( " + id + ", " + field.Text + "," + type.Text + "," + datatype.Text + "," + len.Text + "," + buis.Text + ");"; 
                      com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  }
    }
```

I am getting an error in the last line.Error is :
   An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.
    Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'of'.
    Can anyone help me in sorting this out.

Comment: Display an example com.CommandText which failed - the key will be in there - also, you probably need quotes round your text fields..

Comment: If you are inserting text fields you should wrap them with quotes.

Comment: can you tell me where should I wrap them with quotes?

Comment: DeepanshiBansal - see the answer provided by @DmitriyZapevalov, this is the correct way to write ado.net. **Always** use parameters in your database calls.

Comment: You should also always wrap your database connections in `using` blocks to ensure they are closed as soon as you are done with them. Otherwise you chance having open connections that stay around longer than necessary which can lead to performance problems (among other things).

Answer (score 6):

It is bad idea to integrate text from TextBox to the Query.

You have to add text as parameters:

```
com.CommandText = "insert into tbl_srsdata(id,field,[type_of_control],datatype,length,other_buisness_rules) values(@id,@field,@type,@datatype,@len,@buis)";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", field.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datatype", datatype.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@len", len.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buis", buis.Text);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Integrating text directly to the Query could lead to errors and security problems.

I don't know what is the logics of your program. But I suggest (it could be wrong) to write it like this:

```
if (!Table1.Items.Any())
    return;

string strInsertCmd = 
    "insert into tbl_srsdata(id,field,[type_of_control],datatype,length,other_buisness_rules)"+
    "values(@id,@field,@type,@datatype,@len,@buis)";

using (var com = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strInsertCmd, objconn.con))
{
    var rows = Table1.Items;
    int id;
    id = Redirect.identity;
    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Table1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        var field = Table1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
        var type = Table1.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
        var datatype = Table1.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
        var len = Table1.Columns[3].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
        var buis = Table1.Columns[4].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;

        com.Parameters.Clear();
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", field.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datatype", datatype.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@len", len.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buis", buis.Text);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. !! It worked for the first time but when it goes to the outer loop and again comes inside the second loop it gives an error on com.ExecuteNonQuery() and says: The variable name '@id' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Comment: Try to add `com.Parameters.Clear();` before first `AddWithValue()`.

Comment: Also it seems that you have logic error. Since you're taking same `Cell` for all parameters. Probably there must be only one `Rows` loop. I'll suggest rewritten version.

Answer (score 0):

Please change command text as below

```
    "insert into tbl_srsdata(id,field,[type_of_control],datatype,length,other_buisness_rules) values( " + id + ", '" + field.Text + "','" + type.Text + "','" + datatype.Text + "'," + len.Text + ",'" + buis.Text + "');"
```

Comment: You should always parameterize your queries to avoid syntax errors and sql injection attacks. You also did not consider what if the passed in parameter contains a tick/single quote.

Comment: It is totally based on what user wants to use. The answer was for the problem she was facing. I dont think you downvote for a correct answer. @Igor your note might be an enhancement.

Comment: @AkashAmin - My down vote is in no way subjective. The proposed fix does not solve the problem. What if `datatype.Text` contains the string `"some ' datatype"`? Then the problem would still occur wouldn't it? Building query strings without the use of parameterized sql is a very bad practice and should never be suggested as an answer even if the parameters are escaped and checked (which they are not in this answer either).

Comment: @Igor I totally agree with your answer, but you don't down vote, you can add a comment in the answer. You can always get different answers from different people.

Answer (score -1):

There can be many reasons why that happens. You could've provided the input you were trying to insert.

Anyways, you have to check your input data:

- Are there parts of the `INSERT` data that are non-numeric or text? If so, string literals need to be enclosed in single quotes (`'`).
- If the input IS a string literal, check to see if that input itself contains single quotes. If it does, you need to escape it using two single quotes (`''`).

Comment: Although it might be a quick fix this is definitly not the recommended way to execute ado.net commands. You should always parameterize your queries to avoid syntax errors and sql injection attacks.